# Downloading Components log filled with 'm2repository_47.zip' URL, and never downloads

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Trying to download the SDK components in the install process for Android Studio, but the log is just showing the same URL being repeated several times a second. I have already tried disabling firewall and checking if the URL is accessible from chrome (it is). Also tried running as Administrator and setting the SDK install location to 3 different drives.

I have left this screen open for half an hour and is still showing the exact same thing, with no progress.

[image]

Comment: So you are saying it is accessible from Chrome?

Comment: if the problem persists add a bug report